# How do you remove the Firefox limit on (20) popups?

Tags: firefox, popups

This is useful for Firefox benchmarks (how well it handles multiple tabs via execution of a script).

Comment: Did you look through `about:config` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open a new tab and type into the address bar `about:config?filter=dom.popup_maximum` and press Enter. If you receive a warning, click the button that says "I'll be careful, I promise".
2. Double click on the `dom.popup_maximum` preference and a popup will appear.
3. Change the value to your choice (default is 20) and press OK.

[More information](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.popup_maximum) on the preference.

[image: Image for guidance].

Answer (score 1):

Type about:config into your address bar, reassure Firefox that you'll be careful and search for dom.popup_maximum. Change the value to whatever you'd like.